# Keyboard forgets it is Japanese

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout, mozc

My Japanese layout keyboard uses `mozc` for input - usually in straight-forward direct input mode - but will occasionally switch back to the default US English layout. There is no obvious pattern or error message that appears when this happens. It used to happen very rarely, but recently it's been a few times a day, which fair mucks up my `vim` session if I'm not paying attention.

My `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
XKBMODEL="pc104"
XKBLAYOUT="jp"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

`setxkbmap -layout jp` will return the keymap to normal, but why is this happening? Where could I look to find out further information?

Answer (score 1):

It might be Ubuntu's keyboard layout switching, which defaults to using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (<kbd>Super</kbd> is usually the Windows key) to switch keyboard layouts.

Open the `Text Entry` system settings application and see if English is in the input sources list. If it is, you can either remove it by selecting it and clicking the `—` button at the bottom or you can change the input source switching keys on the right to something you're less likely to press.

Comment: I don't think I'm fat-fingering the `Super+Space`, although that's always a possibility... I've deleted the English option anyway and I'll see how it goes.